# how to save datepicker to sharedpreferences

Tags: android, datepicker, sharedpreferences

Is there a way to save a datepicker data to sharedpreferences? If so, can you give me some codes on how to do it? I'm going to use datepicker to save user's date of birth. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You save datepicker data same way you do for any other data. Get result from date picker and put into prefs. Everything you need is o in docs or tons of tutorials out there. So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can, in a roundabout way. From the year/month/day values of the DatePicker, construct a `java.util.Date` object. Then call `getTime()` on that object - it would return the date as a very long number (# of milliseconds since year 1970) as datatype `long`. Then you can store that in `SharedPreferences` using `putLong()` and retrieve it using `getLong()`.

To place the date back into the picker, construct a `Date` object using the `long` value, then retrieve year/month/day from it.

Alternatively, you can save year/month/day as three separate preference items.

EDIT: here's a sample. The DatePicker object comes from somewhere in your app - I wouldn't know.

```
DatePicker dp; //Where does this come from? You tell me.
Date d = new Date(dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDay());
SharedPreferences Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Ctxt);
Prefs.edit().putLong("Birthday", d.getTime()).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks but what I mean is to give me some snippets of codes so that would be my guide to do it.

Comment: See the edit. But please note that this is heavily frowned upon here at StackOverflow. Read [this](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: Thanks Seva, I will try to understand this concept and hopefully be able to apply it.