# Tell me how to keep your date picker custom settings after exiting app

Tags: javascript, java, android, datepicker

I want to create a simple d-day app.

The code I've got resets the date you set in the date picker when you quit and restart the app

I'd like the dating picker to retain user settings.

As a result, the d-day counter is updated and counted after one day as user settings are maintained.

Please take a look at the code and advise

```js
package your.pack;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DatecalActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 
 private TextView ddayText;
 private TextView todayText;
 private TextView resultText;
 private Button dateButton;
 
 private int tYear;        
 private int tMonth;
 private int tDay;
 
 private int dYear=1;      
 private int dMonth=1;
 private int dDay=1;
 
 
 private long d;
 private long t;
 private long r;
 
 private int resultNumber=0;
 
 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID=0;
 
 
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        ddayText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dday);
        todayText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.today);
        resultText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        dateButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
        
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
         
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showDialog(0);//----------------
   }
  });
        
        
        
        Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();             
        tYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        tMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        tDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        
        Calendar dCalendar =Calendar.getInstance();
        dCalendar.set(dYear,dMonth, dDay);
        
        t=calendar.getTimeInMillis();               
        d=dCalendar.getTimeInMillis();             
        r=(d-t)/(24*60*60*1000);               
        
        resultNumber=(int)r+1;
        updateDisplay();        
        
    }//OnCreate end
    
    private void updateDisplay(){
     
     todayText.setText(String.format("%d년 %d월 %d일",tYear, tMonth+1,tDay));
     ddayText.setText(String.format("%d년 %d월 %d일",dYear, dMonth+1,dDay));
     
     if(resultNumber>=0){
     resultText.setText(String.format("D-%d", resultNumber));
     }
     else{
      int absR=Math.abs(resultNumber);
      resultText.setText(String.format("D+%d", absR));
     }
    }
    
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dDateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
    int dayOfMonth) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   dYear=year;
   dMonth=monthOfYear;
   dDay=dayOfMonth;
   final Calendar dCalendar =Calendar.getInstance();
         dCalendar.set(dYear,dMonth, dDay);
         
         d=dCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
         r=(d-t)/(24*60*60*1000);
         
         resultNumber=(int)r;
   updateDisplay();
  }
 };
 
 
    @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
  if(id==DATE_DIALOG_ID){
  return new DatePickerDialog(this,dDateSetListener,tYear,tMonth,tDay);
   }
  return null;
 }
    
 
}//DatecalActivity end
```

Comment: You want to [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162865/how-to-save-datepicker-to-sharedpreferences) the date?

Comment: yes. i want to save the date

Comment: @JeroenHeier May I ask for your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your datepicker picked date in sharedpreference and get it back when app launches again.

```
DatePicker dp; 
Date d = new Date(dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDay());
SharedPreferences Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Ctxt);
Prefs.edit().putLong("datePickerValue", d.getTime()).commit();
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but how do I apply it to my code ?;

Comment: In your **onDateSet** methd, you are getting three values i.e year, month and day. Pass these values in Date constructor as mentioned above. Then apply the logic as above but first, read about **sharedpreference**.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation
I am learning a lot
But I keep getting getDefaultSharedPreferences (Ctxt);
(Ctxt); is in error
How should Ctxt be handled?

Comment: Put a snippet or logcat so that i can understand what error you are getting.

Comment: onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
...
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("dday", Widget.MODE_PRIVATE);
long millis = pref.getLong("date",dCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth)
.... 
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("dday", Widget.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putLong("date",dCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
            editor.commit();

Comment: I wrote the code like that and it does not work ...
It is also wrong
Please advise

Answer (score 1):

That is what you are looking for:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

On this link you will learn how to save strings in SharedPreferences, using a XML file the keep your data even if you kill your app :D

Comment: Your advice has helped me. :D

Comment: I tried to go through the example but it does not work ... Sorry, I need your advice

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the date that was selected to shared prefs some way and then pull it from the prefs if they exist when the app launches. How you store that date data would be up to you and how you want to do it.